# LocalSettings and background tasks WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, local-storage, background-task

How to change values in Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings with background task. I use such code like back ground task:

```
namespace MainTask
{
    public sealed class Task :IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            var storage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            int i = (int)storage.Values["var"];
            i++;

            storage.Values["val"] = i;

            _deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Background task started and there is in livecycle events in debugger and it reads the storage. But Values["val"] does not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace MainTask
{
    public sealed class Task :IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            var storage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            int i = (int)storage.Values["var"];
            i++;

            storage.Values.Remove("val");
            storage.Values.Add("val", i);

            _deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```